# How can I swap URL parameters and discarding others with mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, configuration

I need to redirect the simplified:

```
/search.html?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3&location=UK
```

To:

```
/search/United-Kingdom/arg4=val2&arg5=val1
```

Parameters may be in any order or missing, location is a code with expansions in a map file (UK United Kingdom, etc).

If there are no matching parameters redirect to:

```
/search-info/
```

Current code for location expansion:

```
RewriteMap location_map txt:/path/to/locations_map.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*search.html.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*location=([^&]+).* [NC]
RewriteCond ${location_map:%1} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search/%1/ [R=301]
```

**How can I swap out the parameter names and discard parameters that aren't needed (i.e. param3 above)?**

Answer (score 1):

This would work if it weren't the changing parameter order requirement. Can't you make the order constant?

```
RewriteMap location_map txt:/path/to/locations_map.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /search.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (param1=(.+?)&)?(param2=(.+?)&)?(param3=(.+?)&)?location=(.+?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search/${location_map:%7}/?arg4=%4&arg5=%2 [R=301,last]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /search.html [NC]
RewriteRule / /search-info/ [last]
```